# Prefixchar by discord bot

Tags: c#, bots, discord

Have a prob with this: x.PrefixChar = '!';
How to delete this "!", bot doesn`t work without prefixchar, but i need empty prefix char.

sorry for bad english.

Comment: @RyanTernier - that's not valid C#.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the type of `PrefixChar` is `char`, this is not possible.

If it were a *nullable* char (that is a `char?`), you could assign `null` to it.

Looks like this is simply not an option for discord.

Answer (score 0):

Discord bot does not work without x.PrefixChar = '!', this problem is unsolvable %)
thanks for answers, just c# things /shrug